# glScalef for raster fonts, OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts, ftgl

I have a simple question. I'm using FTGL library for drawing my `PixmapFont` in my game application. My question is - is it possible to use `glScalef()` to scale raster font, or not? From what I understand, if I have to use `glRasterPos()` instead of `glTranslatef()` it also probably considers `glScalef()` function? But if so, isn't there any way of scaling this font?

This is what I need scaling for:

I can change it's size, by simply putting this:

```
font->FaceSize(12);
```

But it gives me blurry effect for such small font. From what I've read somewhere, it is good to render font with larger size - e.g. 72 - and then to scale it down, because it gives better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pixmap (raster) fonts, you need to use [texture fonts](http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/docs/html/ftgl-tutorial.html). This draws the font as a texture mapped to triangle primitives, which is far more flexible and widely supported than drawing directly to the framebuffer. See also the [`FTTextureFont` documentation](http://ftgl.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classFTTextureFont.html).

Because it's just rendering OpenGL primitives, this approach considers all the usual transformations you set with `glTranslatef`, `glScalef` and so on. For the cleanest result, use `glOrtho` to set a pixel-perfect projection matrix.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. I was wondering if pixmap fonts were a good choice. Now I know it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenGL bitmap drawing functions (glBitmap), are not affected by the transformation pipeline, as they go directly to the framebuffer. However the bitmap drawing functions always used to be slow, poorly supported and have been removed from later versions of OpenGL entirely.

Comment: As usually - very helpful. Thanks, datenwolf.